# Where is the NVCUVID documentation?

Tags: c++, video, cuda

The only official documentation I could find for NVCUVID was [a few samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-video-decoder-d3d9-api) on NVIDIA's CUDA documentation page. Is there a full API reference (i.e. what the functions do) for NVCUVID anywhere?

Comment: 3 years later and still nothing

Answer (score 1):

There is an API specification from August 210 here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15668-s11/www/cuda-doc/CUDA_VideoDecoder_Library.pdf

Comment: That's a short tutorial, not an API specification, and it's the same document you can find at the address I linked to, on NVIDIA's site.

Comment: @Dr_Asik The linked pdf file is as good as the documentation gets. You should also be able to find it in the "doc" directory of your cuda install location. However, it does provide an explaination of the functions, so I'm a bit confused about what you're looking for.

Comment: It only briefly talks about 5 functions. There are many more in NVCUVID, and many data structures. For instance, where is the documentation for cuvidCreateVideoParser?

Comment: cuvidCreateVideoParser is windows only, and I believe they state that they assume most people will use their own parsers (I'm going off memory from a year or two ago, so maybe things have changed). Honestly the best way to learn about the CUVID functions is to look at the samples using them, or at least that's what I did